# iPhone Meeting Creation?

Tags: iphone, calendar.app

The keynote that first introduced us iPhone users to our long sought for OS 3 claimed with an onscreen feature list that we would be able to create meeting invitations on our phones. This seems to be a false claim. No one seems to have figured out a way to do so. This feature would be critically beneficial to my smartphone usage. Can anyone help me with a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Calendar --> Add Event (+) --> Invitees -->

- Type in Contact Name or Email address

This appears to be a feature that is only available with ActiveSync enabled...?  Or at least the secondary iPod touch doesn't show it.... Where the iPhone 3GS that I have activeSync'd does....

Comment: I have this on my iPod touch 1st gen with iPhone OS 3.

Comment: The only problem is that the invite option only shows if the meeting is on my exchange calendar. If I'm trying to use a personal calendar, this entire field disappears from the event info. I'm on OS 3 with a 3G. Any thoughts?